# How to submit 2FA credentials for my app in google playstore console

Tags: android, google-play, publishing, androidpublisher

I have an app that requires **checkmobi phone number verification for login**. However, when app was published to playstore, it was rejected because login credentials were not supplied. **How do I supply this sort of credentials to google playstore console**

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide it in the `App Content` section. Follow the steps.

1. Click on `App Content`
   [image]
2. Click on `Manage` for `App Access`.
   [image]
3. Click on `All or some functionality is restricted`.
   [image]
4. Click on `Add new instructions`. This dialog will appear.
   [image]
5. Provide the auth phone number(In Username/Phone number) and otp(I password).
6. Click on apply. It will be saved and create one more release and then your app will be published.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, The OTP is only generated when you enter the phone number. That is, when you enter the phone number, you receive a phone call from checkmobi and the last 4 digits of the calling number is your otp

Comment: Then you need to add in instructions to add their own credentials and then they receive a call

Comment: Can you show me a demo please?

Comment: Hold on. Do you have a test user thing in `checkmobi` or anything like that you enter phone number and you have same otp like how Firebase Auth has?

Comment: No. They do no have that

Comment: then I am not sure I can help you.

Comment: I will search and then let you know

Comment: Alright. Thanks

Comment: I had a lot of search but could not find anything sorry.

Comment: Thanks man... You've done noble

Comment: @JosephOfem did you find any solution? I'm facing the same problem. Previously my app didn't have 2FA but now it has, when I republished the new version it was removed some days after, but I don't know what to do now. 2FA is the only way allowed to login, so its needed a 3rd party app on mobile to check the access. Google is asking me some credentials, but is not possible now with 2FA

Comment: @pmiranda I was able to solve it by doing the following: 1. Create a demo account with a password similar to what you are expecting as the 2FA token; 2. Add the login credentials to your app constants (I add mine to local.properties file and access it through BuildConfig class). 3. Modify your login service to bypass the 2FA verification if the credentials match the demo account details. You may have to confirm with the backend service to also bypass the 2FA if the login service from an API.

Comment: @JosephOfem This is wrong on so many levels. Google literally asks us to create backdoor in our PRODUCTION apps. Even Apple is capable to accept video of app instead of credentials.

Comment: @JosephOfem If you rely on 2FA, then you don't wanna create re-usable OTP (ONE-TIME password. If someone somehow steals it, then he can access your app or your systems easily. If you use 2FA and generates re-usable codes then you don't use 2FA. Chain is only strong as weakest part.

Comment: @JerabekJakub How do you suggest i resolve this issue?

Comment: @JosephOfem I do not, this is bad move from Google. I was used to bypass this requirement by making video. That was suitable for Apple for years. I still hope, Google will accept it as well. Otherwise I will probably create fake screens in app that will show up after entering "re-usable" credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up with rejection of your application due to missing credentials and you are not able to provide them (e.g. they are really one-time), you can send appeal to Google and then, they are open to accept video of your application. You have to record each screen for at least 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?#app_access

> If your app typically requires a 2-Step Verification code or One Time Password, provide us with reusable login credentials that do not expire.

Unfortunately it seems the official Google mantra is to code your app so that the play store testers don't have to use 2FA.